# redirecting when link ends with certain text [not extension !] - removing that last text

Tags: string, .htaccess, redirect

couldn't find the right answer so here goes my question:

- We've moved our webshop to a different platform (from Virtuemart to Opencart 2.0.3.2).
- the old links around the internet leading to our products are like https://www.name.ext/category/productcode-detail
- the new links come without the '-detail' at the end of it

I've found an extension that'll add the -detail to the product links, but I'd rather have a .htaccess redirect to remove '-detail' on those specific links.

This way, all links on the internet are still valid (but redirected) and Google e.g. can redo the indexing whilst not loosing all SEO earlier.

Can it be done?

Comment: by the way; we've got about 5000 products, so redirecting every single specific item would not be an option. They all end on -detail for now 'though.

Comment: And how can that "-detail" actually look like? Is it static? Does it have a pattern? Anything?

Comment: The former webshop gave out https://www.name.ext/category/productcode-detail
So links tou our products are out there and point to that type of address.
We'd like to receive people on that address and redirect them to https://www.name.ext/category/productcode

Comment: So it is a literal string.

Answer (score 0):

Considering your comments to the question this probably is the correct approach. I fail to understand why you couldn't find an answer to this here on SO, it looks absolutely straight forward.

I *assume* that "category" is meant as a placeholder which can actually take different forms. Same with the "productcode". Since you did not provide any pattern or similar this suggestion is generic:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?(\w+)/(\w+)-detail$ /$1/$2 [R=301]
```

Note however that your question is vague. I assume that you need to tweak that suggestion, so that other references won't break. Most likely you need a blacklist to prevent some not product related stuff from getting rewritten. But again: since your question is vague there is nothing more specific we can suggest than the above.

It is a good idea to start out with a 302 temporary redirection and only change that to a 301 permanent redirection later, once you are certain everything is correctly set up. That prevents caching issues while trying things out...

This implementation will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a dynamic configuration file (".htaccess" file). Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded inside the http server and enabled in the http host. In case you use a dynamic configuration file you need to take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that it is located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"). Those dynamic configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).

Comment: ah too bad, that gave me a 500 on the server.

you're right, the /category can be gent, ladies, etc.
also the productcode is a unique string.
the -detail is static however.

Comment: @MennoVindit I _do_ have to apologize, it is `RewriteRule`, not `RedirectRule`! I fixed the answer.

Comment: Too bad... No success:
https://vintagehatter.com/en/gents-hats/h-5011-59-n01-detail

Comment: OK, the pattern of that URL you now posted in the comment explains... It is a third level. That is why the rule I posted does not apply. It is easy to fix for sure. Good luck!